# metaClass property on java classes in groovy

Tags: java, groovy, metaprogramming

i'm learning groovy and I have a question concerning its metaprogramming facilities. From what I understand every object in groovy implements the groovy.lang.GroovyObject interface (implicitly added by groovy compiler). The latter interface contains the method getMetaClass() so I can do the following:

```
class MyGroovyClass{
}
def myGroovyClass = new MyGroovyClass();
println myGroovyClass.metaClass.name
```

The thing that I don't understand is how objects compiled by a java compiler like java.lang.String get the metaClass property. Is this property defined in the actually MetaClass object that gets associated with java classes through the MetaClassRegistry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to methods added through the meta-object protocol, Groovy also augments classes in the JDK with additional methods defined in the [`groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html) class.  `List` and other collections get methods like `each` and `collect`.  The same mechanism adds a `getMetaClass` method to `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: Ok, but how do these methods defined in groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods get called? Does the groovy compiler explicitly look for method calls to jdk classes and intercept these to generate byte-code that calls the methods defined in DefaultGroovyMethods? Does this mean that only java classes defined in the jdk get the getMetaClass() method?

Comment: @JamesV.H. Well, Groovy objects obviously have the property--what do you mean by "get the method"?

Comment: @DaveNewton yeah I understand that objects compiled in groovy have the property, no problem there.Classes compiled with the java compiler obviously don't have the property, still we can call the metaClass property on them. Ataylor commented where the added methods are defined (in DefaultGroovyMehods) but not HOW the association mechanism works.

Comment: @JamesV.H. The groovy method dispatch mechanism; it's described in the presentation.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks for the reference but it did not explain my question. Apparantly, this is handled as a special case and custom code is written for it in the groovy core. See [link](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/How-does-the-magic-about-the-Groovy-JDK-work-td363320.html#a363322)

Comment: @JamesV.H. Just bear in mind that is quite old. Also, mixins aren't temporary like categories are; I'd be more likely to believe they share a similar mechanism.

Comment: Just a quick note that it looks like in Groovy 2.0, the monolithic DefaultGroovyMethods class is getting split into separate classes per class they decorate

Answer (score 1):

Correct, POJOs have their metaclasses looked up in the registry.

[This presentation](http://skillsmatter.com/downloads/Groovy%20User%20Group%20December%202006.pdf) provides a high-level overview of how metaclasses are used by both Groovy and POJ objects. (With the caveat that it's a little old.)

Comment: link is broken :S